# TableView split animation segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uistoryboardsegue

I'm working on a custom animation segue that is supposed to work like this:

```
User taps cell in table view,
table view splits underneath the selected cell,
bottom half translates down, upper half translates up to reveal destination view
```

Unfortunately I've been having trouble with splitting the view into two pieces.  My idea was to create two snapshots of the view, then alter the bounds of those snapshots, one to represent the bottom and one to represent the top, hide the view underneath and then translate the snapshots.

However, there are two problems: 1) If the source view hides or changes alpha, the snapshots change as well (because the only way to shot the snapshots is to make them subviews of the source view). and 2) The destination view shows up late after a black screen.

Any ideas as to what the problem is? Or maybe a new direction to take it?

Heres the code:

```
@interface ExpandTableViewSegue()

// there are these also in header
// UIImageView *topView;
// UIImageView *bottomView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *containerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *imageContainerViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *backgroundView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end

@implementation ExpandTableViewSegue


- (void)perform {
    self.navigationController = [self.sourceViewController navigationController];

    [self pushDestinationControllerToNavigationStack];
    self.backgroundView = [[self.destinationViewController view] snapshotView];
    [self popTopMostControllerOffStack];

    [self pushImageContainerControllerToNavigationStack];
    [self animateImagesInContainerView];
}

- (void)pushDestinationControllerToNavigationStack {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
}

- (void)pushImageContainerControllerToNavigationStack {
    UIViewController *imageContainerController = [self imageContainerViewController];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageContainerController animated:NO];
}

- (void)animateImagesInContainerView {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        [[self.sourceViewController view]removeFromSuperview];
        [self translateTopImageUp];
        [self translateBottomImageDown];
        [self.containerView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self popTopMostControllerOffStack];
            [self pushDestinationControllerToNavigationStack];
        }
    }];
}
```

EDIT1: (updated code) I solved the first problem... What I did was create a container view which housed both of the snapshot images and then pushed that view onto the navigation stack before performing the animation.
But I'm still having trouble with the second issue, which deals with when the destination controller gets pushed onto the stack.  What I want is for the animation to gradually show the destination view underneath. but right now it shows a black screen (the current view) and then pops into the destination view.

My attempted solution was to quickly push the destination view onto the stack, take a snapshot, and pop it off the stack.
Then continue with the procedure, but add the new snapshot to the background so it would appear behind the first two snapshots.

Any new ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a good approach.  I would take the snapshots, then pass them off to the destinationViewController in the -prepareForSegue: method. Let the destinationViewController handle them, and remove them when your animation is done. 
Alternatively, you could pass the images to the segue if you've subclassed it.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have the top and bottom images being sent from the sourceviewcontroller to the segue subclass now, then the segue handles the animation.